# PayPal application going live. New credentials

Tags: paypal

I use some 3rd party script for processing the PayPal payments. Found it on Github, works perfect. It uses the following credentials:
Username, password, signature.

In sandbox it works perfect. Now I want to go live.

I go to developer.paypal.com -> My apps -> choosing my app -> Show live credentials. 
Now, it shows me:
Endpoint - api.paypal.com
Client ID - xxx
Secret - xxx.

1. However, I can't find the ones I actually need. Where do I get them ?
2. What these credentials are used for ? (client id, secret, endpoint) They don't appear anywhere in the code of my payment script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Classic API credentials:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

Comment: can you explain what i need when integrate paypal in to my android app for android sdk or mobile payment libreary jar.And how can i register app with sandbox and live with end to end in step by step process please and thanks